# Windows 10 can´t connect to local network with wifi and ethernet

Tags: windows-10, networking, home-networking, network-adapter, fritzbox

for a few days now I’ve got a really strange problem with my network at home which (as far as I know) only affects my Windows 10 machines.

**My problem:**

My main computer is usually connected via Ethernet directly to our router (FritzBox 7590 (very popular in Germany)) and every time I come home and start my computer it says “no internet” or “unidentified network” to my Ethernet connection. If I then try to connect to my network using Wi-Fi it says no Internet, but then I can reach my router web interface (192.168.178.1) and after doing some stuff like restarting my computer and or router, disabling and re-enabling my network driver I can sometimes get back access to the internet. This only occurs on my Windows machines, phones(iOS and Android), Linux machines and esp32s still work.

On one of my machines Ethernet isn't usable at all anymore, only Wi-Fi.

To summarize it:

- On one machine Ethernet won´t work at all
- Only on Windows machines are affected
- Once connected it continues working until disconnection

**I`ve tried:**

- Software/Firmware updates(Router, Switches, Repeaters, Windows)
- Checked some logs (Router, Repeater)
- Some google research
- Multiple restarts and reconnections of everything

Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Thanks for your answers!
(In case anyone has a better title or found spelling or grammar mistakes, feel free to write me or edit them)

Comment: Try updating the firmware on the router. Since the router works for non-Windows machines, this is a good first step.

Comment: @John Thanks John for your fast answer, sadly I already tried that yesterday.

Comment: Contact Fritz Support. Windows Networking is very robust, so see what Fritz says.

Comment: [Check the event log of the FRITZ!Box](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/knowledge-base/publication/show/27_Wi-Fi-connection-drops-frequently/) and that of Windows Event Viewer for interesting messages. Check also in the FRITZ!Box the Security settings & firewall and perhaps the MAC address filter.

Comment: Are your Windows 10 machines each connected directly to the FritzBox ethernet ports or are there any other things in between (router/switch/PowerLine setup etc.) that the other machines don't have? Long shot but maybe something in the middle is crashing or going to sleep when traffic drops off.

Comment: Never mind - just re-read and saw you stated it was connected directly.